# How to get CaseIDs of Failed test cases in a test run using testrail API

Tags: testrail

This is my test run in test rail :
[image]

How do I get the list of Case IDs of the test cases which are failed status through testrail API?

**What I tried based on the documentation https://support.testrail.com/hc/en-us/articles/7077819312404-Results :**

```
curl -s -u $TESTRAIL_EMAIL:$TESTRAIL_PW -X GET "$TESTRAIL_URL/index.php?/api/v2/get_results_for_run/$TESTRAIL_RUN_ID" | jq 'group_by(.test_id) | map(max_by(.created_on))' | jq '[.[] | select(.status_id != 1)]'
```

*(Explanation : Get all results of a testrun.
Group it by `test_id`. From Each group take the latest result only. Filter by `status_id != 1` (ie, status is not pass))*

Output :

```
[
  {
    "id": 966943,
    "test_id": 2559942,
    "status_id": null,
    "created_on": 1684909080,
    "assignedto_id": 531,
    "comment": null,
    "version": null,
    "elapsed": null,
    "defects": null,
    "created_by": 546,
    "custom_step_results": null,
    "attachment_ids": []
  },
  {
    "id": 967944,
    "test_id": 2559944,
    "status_id": 5,
    "created_on": 1684936836,
    "assignedto_id": null,
    "comment": null,
    "version": null,
    "elapsed": null,
    "defects": null,
    "created_by": 546,
    "custom_step_results": null,
    "attachment_ids": []
  }
]
```

But this results doesn't have the Case ID of the test cases. Also this doesn't include `untested` tests. Also the i am only able to filter with `.status_id` and not the actual status like `Pass` `Failed` `Untested` etc

Is there a way to achieve my need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to utilize the 'get_results_for_run' endpoint, obtaining the Case IDs is not feasible since the current response format does not include the 'Case_id.'

However, an alternative endpoint to retrieve the data you've submitted is available, which involves using the 'get_tests' endpoint.

With the ‘get_tests’ endpoint, your request looks like this :

GET index.php?/api/v2/get_tests/{run_id}

and the response looks like the below :

```
{
   "assignedto_id": 1,
   "case_id": 1,
   "custom_expected": "..",
   "custom_preconds": "..",
   "custom_steps_separated": [
       {
           "content": "Step 1",
           "expected": "Expected Result 1"
       },
       {
           "content": "Step 2",
           "expected": "Expected Result 2"
       }
   ],
   "estimate": "1m 5s",
   "estimate_forecast": null,
   "id": 100,
   "priority_id": 2,
   "run_id": 1,
   "status_id": 5,
   "title": "Verify line spacing on multi-page document",
   "type_id": 4
}
```

From here you will find the Case IDs for the tests that are available in the run and you can further filter the response based on the status_id.

For example:

GET index.php?/api/v2/get_tests/{run_id}&status_id=5

This filter will refine the results to include tests with the status "Failed".

Kindly be aware that in the TestRail API, it's not feasible to filter tests based on the status name (e.g., Pass, Fail). We must always employ the 'status_id' for filtering purposes.

Reference :
https://support.testrail.com/hc/en-us/articles/7077935129364-Statuses#getstatuses

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for. However I couldn't see information about get_tests API in the documentation you linked. Where did you find this? I'm curious

Comment: Here is the final command which worked for me for anyone who want to use it  :   `curl -s -u $TESTRAIL_EMAIL:$TESTRAIL_PW -X GET "$TESTRAIL_URL/index.php?/api/v2/get_tests/$TESTRAIL_RUN_ID&status_id=5"  | jq -r '.[] | {case_id}'`